# Eigenvalue of $A$ is root of $p(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on this proof problem:

[image]

I have part (a) done.  I think this is the Cayley Hamilton Theorem, so I got some insight from Wikipedia.  I am a little confused with part (b) though because I feel that the converse of the statement is true, and I guess I can't think of a good counter example?

Any advice?

Comment: The question in part $(a)$ should be the other way around.

Comment: What do you mean Mhenni?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: I'm not sure why you say that.  The question in part a) is correct as stated (and is a rather standard linear algebra result).  It is true that this is not the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.  I have sketched a proof in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A \neq 0$ but $A^2 = 0$.

By the way, I don't think that the proof of part a) is only the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.  You also need to know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ have the same real roots.

**Added**: Here is a sketch proof of part a): let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, so there is a nonzero $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $Av = \lambda v$.  Then $v$ is an eigenvector for $p(A)$ with eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$.  On the other hand $p(A) = 0$....

Comment: So do you we just include a polynomial q?  Why do we specifically multiply q(A) to p(A)?

Comment: I apologize: I had somehow gotten it into my head that the converse was the statement that if $p(A) = 0$ then the only roots of $p$ are the eigenvalues.  That was a mistake.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So I used a matrix A=[[2 -2] [2 -2]] and $A^{2}$ = 0.
So when I looked for its eigenvalues using the characteristic equation it gave me $\lambda$ = 0.  Then I plugged in the matrix *A* for the polynomial equation.  I got 0.  What did I do wrong?  Is my current matrix for *A* not a good counterexample?

Comment: The counterexample involves not just a matrix but a polynomial.  You want a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A) \neq 0$ but $p(\lambda) = 0$ for all eigenvalues of $A$.  So what polynomial should you choose for your matrix $A$?

Comment: Well matrix *A* is a nilpotent matrix, right?  So that means the eigenvalue is 0, which I got.  I guess I don't really what polynomial to choose.  It's not the characteristic equation, right?

Comment: Right, it can't be the characteristic polynomial because you don't want the matrix to satisfy it.  What is the smallest polynomial which has the eigenvalue as a root?